# Target the first and last anchor in an unordered list's list item

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target the first and last anchor within a list-item of an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried:

```
.menu ul .last a {}
.menu ul.last a {}
.menu ul li .last a {}
.menu ul li.last a {}
```

I need to target the anchor as I need to remove the border of the first and last anchor. I can't use (or at least I don't think I can) border on the `<li>`, as it needs some vertical padding so the separator border is not vertically flush.

Comment: What's your HTML? Are you actually declaring `<li class="last">`?

Comment: No, just <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>

Comment: Is `.menu` the element that contains `<ul>`?

Comment: Thanks, boltclock! See my response below, i was missing the class on the li itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't need to worry about old browsers, use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes on the list items, like so:

```css
/* Because we are looking at the <li> children of your <ul> */
.menu ul li:first-child a {}
.menu ul li:last-child a {}
```

However, support for CSS3 `:last-child` is pretty poor right now, so a more browser-compatible alternative is to manually give the last list item a `last` class, like so (and doing the same for first):

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then, you can use these selectors:

```css
.menu ul li.first a {}
.menu ul li.last a {}
```

Comment: +1 you beat me to it.  :)  The `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors are actually part of CSS2.  Most versions of IE lack proper support for them (although they work in IE9) but other browsers should be okay. Your work-around is probably safer for now.

Comment: @eaj: No, `:last-child` is CSS3-only.

Comment: I stand corrected. `:first-child` is CSS2 and `:last-child` is CSS3.

Comment: @eaj: I'm still puzzled as to why they didn't come up with both together in CSS2 :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`:first-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) and [`:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) pseudo-class selectors:

```
<style type="text/css">
.menu ul li:first-child a {
  color: green;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">baker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">charlie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">delta</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but CSS 2 only, I shouldve stated that. BoltClock's comment give me the nudge i needed. Thanks again.

Comment: heads up: will work on everything except IE 6 and 7, slightly buggy on 8.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you require are the :first-child and :last-child selectors.

```
.menu ul li:first-child a
.menu ul li:last-child a
```