# First child selection

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In this exercise I was curious to learn how the first-child selector works. Trying to select the `h1` tag and give it a color for example.

```css
.col1:first-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col1">
  <h1> This is  something awesome!</h1>
  <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorlike).</p>
  <button type="button" class="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Note: The question relates only to the first-child and how it actually works, as  I think that the `h1` is the first child of div col1 but with no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219260/target-the-first-and-last-anchor-in-an-unordered-lists-list-item or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class?rq=1 or one of the other 50 times this question has been asked here :-)

Comment: @TylerH: The two of these are completely different questions...

Comment: @BoltClock They both tell you how to use :first-child correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.col1:first-child` means "A member of `col1` that is the first child of *its parent*" not "The first child *of* each element that is a member of `col1`".

For that you need to insert a *child combinator*:

```
.col1 > :first-child {}
```

Comment: I had a thorough answer to this question from years ago but I had written it to [debunk the same misconception in an otherwise completely unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4195253/revisions). I'm still looking for a question on this subject that's worth migrating it to. And this question ain't it :(

Comment: Thank you for explaining that!